# Grep consecutive lines with duplicates field values.

Tags: linux, string, unix, grep

I can't figure out how to `grep` the lines I want in this file:

```
8.txt  07:34:12 -> CONTENT START
8.txt  07:34:42 <-CONTENT END
8.txt  07:35:08 -> CONTENT START
8.txt  07:36:33 <-CONTENT END
8.txt  07:57:51 -> CONTENT START
8.txt  07:57:52 -> CONTENT START
8.txt  07:58:25 <-CONTENT END
8.txt  07:58:36 -> CONTENT START
8.txt  07:59:24 <-CONTENT END
8.txt  08:20:23 -> CONTENT START
8.txt  08:21:22 <-CONTENT END
8.txt  08:22:44 -> CONTENT START
8.txt  07:34:12 -> CONTENT START
8.txt  08:23:07 <-CONTENT END
8.txt  08:26:35 -> CONTENT START
8.txt  08:27:24 <-CONTENT END
8.txt  08:29:53 -> CONTENT START
8.txt  08:30:28 <-CONTENT END
8.txt  08:30:59 -> CONTENT START
8.txt  08:31:21 <-CONTENT END
8.txt  08:48:28 -> CONTENT START
8.txt  08:48:56 <-CONTENT END
8.txt  09:13:10 -> CONTENT START
8.txt  09:13:40 <-CONTENT END
8.txt  09:13:52 -> CONTENT START
8.txt  09:14:44 <-CONTENT END
8.txt  09:19:50 -> CONTENT START
8.txt  09:20:28 <-CONTENT END
8.txt  09:27:04 -> CONTENT START
8.txt  09:27:40 <-CONTENT END
```

If `CONTENT START` occurrence on consecutive lines then display them.

Output expected:

```
8.txt  07:57:51 -> CONTENT START
8.txt  07:57:52 -> CONTENT START
8.txt  08:22:44 -> CONTENT START
8.txt  07:34:12 -> CONTENT START
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a task for `grep` use `uniq` for this:

```
$ uniq -D -f4 file
8.txt  07:57:51 -> CONTENT START
8.txt  07:57:52 -> CONTENT START
8.txt  08:22:44 -> CONTENT START
8.txt  07:34:12 -> CONTENT START
```

The option `-D` is for displaying the duplicated lines and `-f4` skips the first four fields.

Comment: uniq requires the input to be sorted, the OPs posted sample input isn't.

Comment: No it doesn't Ed, in most circumstances you would want you input sorted first but this is definitely not one of them. Uniq only compare consecutive lines so it's perfect here and hence when it's commonly used with sort. Read `man uniq` for a better explanation.

Comment: Well it certainly seems to be working so I stand corrected, thanks. You live and learn...

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what to do if CONTENT START appears on 3 consecutive lines so this may or may not be what you want:

```
awk -v s="CONTENT START" '$0~s && p~s{print p ORS $0} {p=$0}' file
```